# Store novel-length strings as .txt files or text files in a database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

An online library project I'm mulling over in my mind. Which would be the fastest, the most resource-efficient, and the most developer-friendly? Txt files with their paths stored in the database, or the whole novel stored in a database field.

Definitely feeling .txt files would speed up database queries, but storing the actual novels in the database would simplify the source code.

I will be using Ruby on the Rails Framework, augmented with the MySQL engine. Future features such as text analysis and search functions may also be implemented.

Comment: Is simplified source code really worth it for your users? Sure it might be more "developer-friendly" but who are you designing your application for? Think of the users and what is best/most optimized for them.

Comment: Would you like to perform search on those texts, do you need to perform some analysis, do you need to read a whole text all the time?

Comment: @taro Excellent point, edited question